# Video settings, keyboard not working after update to 22.04

Tags: grub2, keyboard, 22.04, display-resolution

(Gigabyte Z370 Aorus Gaming 5, i7-8700, 32 GB, 500 GB, hardly used)

After updating Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.02, the screen resolution is lowered (I think to HD instead of 4K) and fixed. Also, the (Apple) keyboard is no longer working, not even the Shift key led lights up when pressed. A 'pc' keyboard still works.

I tried to fix it by enabling the bios SGX setting, but this doesn't seem to make any difference to the screen resolution and functioning of the keyboard.

I then changed the GRUB from 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-38-generic' to 5.15.0-69-generic and now the screen resolution and keyboard are functioning again, but I still have no clue what is going on. I mean.. the GRUB 5.19 update is there for a reason, right?

[partial image of startup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvldA.jpg)

Any hints to what is going wrong and how to fix it? I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: You did the fix that would have been suggested. Not every single system is going to like what is added or changed in a kernel update. When there is issue load an older kernel. The next kernel update may be better for you.